# Установка mysql на ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Как поставить mysql и среду с графическим интерфейсом для её администрирования на ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно сервер управления БД:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Широко распространённая  программа с веб-интерфейсом:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin apache2-utils
```

или  ещё проще: (инструмент управления БД, без установки, скачал и открыл в браузере)

```
wget -O - http://www.chive-project.com/Download/Redirect|tar -xzp
```

дополнительно: обратите внимание на совместимые модули для вашего сервера, языка программирования ( для php их надо устанавливать отдельно) и изучите конфигурации для устанавливаемых пакетов

Comment: Shilgen. лучше, наверно, не писать комментарии, а дополнить ответ. кстати, у вас там последняя строка не отформатирована как код.

Comment: Также можно пощупать MySQL Workbench.